# Redirect to the same page in another folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

#### How to redirect to the same page in another folder?

I have a web site with two different languages. Can I redirect to the same page in the other language/folder if I click the language link button?
Example: If I am in register page, when I click on the other language link button, I want to be redirected to the same page in the other language/folder.

The main link of languages is in master page.

***Is this possible?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're using subfolder to manage your culture.
So you'll have for exemple `~/en/Default.aspx` and `~/fr/Default.aspx`.

If thats the case, you case use this piece of code.

```
        //For exemple: /en/Default.aspx
        string currentURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

        //Manage different part of the URL
        string[] urlParts = currentURL.Split(new string[] {"/"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        //Remove the old culture code
        IEnumerable<string> invariantUrlParts = urlParts.Skip(1);

        //Rebuild the URL
        string newUrl = String.Format("~/{0}/{1}", "fr", String.Join("/", invariantUrlParts));

        //Redirect to ~/fr/Default.aspx
        Response.Redirect(newUrl);
```

---

**EDIT**

If you're a fan of one-liner:

```
Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
.Split(new string[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
.Skip(1)
.Aggregate(String.Format("~/{0}", "fr"), (i, j) => i + "/" + j));
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine you have a dropdown with all languages, and upon selection, you want to load the same page in the chosen language...

and assuming you know the current language (in a session variable for example) that is beeing loaded, you could have:

as dropdown:

```
<select id="langSelector" onchange="changeCountry(this.value);">
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="es">Spanish</option>
  <option value="fr">French</option>
</select>
```

in javascript:

```
var currentLanguage = "en"; 
// for example in ASP.NET Webforms
// var currentLanguage = "<%= Session["currentLanguage"] %>";

function changeCountry(selectedLanguage) {
  var preLang = '/' + currentLanguage + '/',
      newLang = '/' + selectedLanguage + '/';  
  document.location = document.location.pathname.replace(preLangig, newLang);
}
```

---

explanation:

in javascript `document.location.pathname` will show the full path after the protocol and domain name, and if you have a simple `/en/` you can replace that with `/fr/` and load the rest again.

to be fail proof, you need to do the `replace` ignoring the case, so `En` or `eN` could also be translated to `fr`.

in that cause you would use this:

```
function changeCountry(selectedLanguage) {
  var newLang = '/' + selectedLanguage + '/';  
  document.location = 
     document.location.pathname.replace(
         /\/<%= Session["currentLanguage"].ToString().ToLower() %>\//i, 
         newLang);
}
```

so you would have:

```
.replace(/\/<%= Session["currentLanguage"].ToString().ToLower() %>\//i, newLang);
```